# Get list of objects shown in Object Manager

Tags: soql, salesforcedx, standard-objects, object

I'm looking for a way to get the list of objects that are shown in Setup->Objects and Fields->Object Manager, either via sfdx command line or SOQL.

If I use:

```
sfdx force:schema:sobject:list
```

It lists the Einstein objects like "AI Application", "AI Application Config", etc. These are not shown in Object Manager. Even adding the "-c standard" to this command does not filter those out.

If I run this SOQL:

```
Select Label, QualifiedApiName, Description from EntityDefinition
```

This also gives me those Einstein objects.

But Object Manager knows to skip those. What is it looking at to know that those objects should not display?

Comment: It has to be SOQL or SFDX, you can't use Apex?

Comment: Do you need to do it programmatically or could you try using [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php)?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, it has to be either of those. I'm trying to do this outside of Salesforce, using a Powershell script.

Answer (score 2):

Try filtering using the `IsCustomizable` property. This property is `true` if custom fields can be defined for the entity, which is the case for the objects shown in the object manager.

```
SELECT Label, QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition WHERE IsCustomizable = true
```